# Where to add captcha in PHP?

Tags: php, webforms

I have a file upload form written in PHP. The form is spread across two pages. On page 1, the user can pick files to upload and on page 2, the code processes the files and moves them into the right directory after verifying the types and such. To increase security of the form, I wish to add a captcha. What I'm wondering is more about how the malicious hack from exploiting the form works. Should I put the captcha onto page 1 where the files are being selected (resulting in the hacker won't be able to select a file to upload from their computer without completing the captcha first) or should I put the captcha on the forms processing page (meaning, don't process the files the hacker selected until the captcha is solved)?

I'm working on other methods of securing the form and file handling, but was looking for advice on how to approach this conceptually.

Thank you!

Comment: Mind posting all your code?

Comment: I don't see how your alternatives would work: The captcha is placed on the first page / script and checked in the second when you submit your form. It's always a 2-step process so doing "it" on one page is not really an option.

Comment: It should be on the first page, why do you even want to let a hacker upload files?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any code, but from what you are saying - it's better to place captcha on page 1, because it takes place before sending any files and therefore preserving server resources.

Answer (score 0):

You place the captcha on the first page, and on the second page the data is only processed if the captcha passes. If it fails, display your message and redirect back to page one for them to try again.